# How to display control on every page which is placed below tabix in the SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have textbox control beneath tablix and wanting to display the textbox value on each page on fixed location on the report. The SSRS is rendering the report correctly when number of rows returned fits on one page and text box is displayed correctly at the designated place. But if the number of rows to be displayed in tablix is more than 10 rows(Added page break group to break to next page upon displaying 10 records on current page), then textbox gets pushed to the next page and not displayed. I want the textbox to display its value on each page.

Any help on this is appreciated.
Thanks

i have already added page breaks based on number of records to be displayed per page.

Comment: did you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image one show Design and if you look at right hand side Text Box Properties (other) category--> Repeat with here you can select with which Tablix you want to repeat. In my case I am repeating it with Tablix 1

[image]

Below Images will show you Text box on every page.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. But my textbox is right below the tablix. So if number of rows displayed in the tablix are more than set on page break, then textbox is not shown.

Comment: you will have to change the position of your Textbox